# C mysql prepared statement problems with bind

Tags: mysql, c, xcode, macos

Hello I am writing a `C` program (no C++) to push data into my `xampp database`. To program I use `Xcode 7.1`

I already got a normal query to work. So now I thought about using prepared statements.

I already found here how to do it:
[How to setup prepared statements for mysql queries in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629866/how-to-setup-prepared-statements-for-mysql-queries-in-c)

But my compiler does not like the code.

```
bind[0].buffer_type= MYSQL_TYPE_LONG;
bind[0].buffer=ppm_value;
bind[0].buffer_length=strlen(ppm_value);
bind[0].is_null=0;
bind[0].length=0;
```

It wants to replace the `.` with `->` but if I do so I get the error:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x60)
```

`ppm_value` is a `int` so I am also not sure if there is a problem with `strlen`.
Do I even need the `buffer_length?`

Could someone please help me.

Comment: I solved my problem i accidentally wrote by the initialization of bind MYSQL_BIND *bind[4] instead of MYSQL_BIND bind[4] thanks for all who tried to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide a pointer:

```
bind[0].buffer = &ppm_value;
bind[0].buffer_length = sizeof(ppm_value);
```

Comment: thanks this solved my integer to pointer warning but it didn't solve my main problem.

Comment: Then your problem is outside the scope of the code you posted and you will need to provide more context